# Install PgAgent for PostgreSQL 9.6 on Windows Server 2019

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, pgagent

I have PostgreSQL 9.6.23 on windows server 2019
i want to install PgAgent for scheduling backup and deletion of data
PostgreSQL Stack Builder's doesn't have PgAgent like newer version
How can i manually install it or if there is any setup file that do so

Answer (score 0):

since you're using a windows server, you can just download [pgAdmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/), it comes built in with pgAgent, which is way easier to get it up and running rather than manually compiling pgAgent. Hope that helps you out!

Comment: I'm running an old postgresql that doesn't have pgagent inside it's stackbuilder